# Google API Client Libraries -PHP : Google Game Services occurs error (code : 500) without any message

Tags: api, server, google-api-php-client, leaderboard

I'm using Google API Client Libraries - PHP and using Service accounts issuing on Google API Console.

I want to get Leaderboards list but error occurs code 500 without any message.

Enabled Google Play Game Management, Google Play Game Services, Google+ API on API Console.

And, Android application using this Leaderboards proper.

**What can I do resolve this problem?**

request codes(PHP)

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/path/to/google-api-php-client/src');
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');

    $client_email = 'myaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $private_key = file_get_contents('/path/to/my_key_file.p12');
    $scopes = array(
            Google_Service_Games::GAMES,
            Google_Service_Games::PLUS_LOGIN
    );

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    }

    $service = new Google_Service_Games($client);
    $response = $service->leaderboards->listLeaderboards();
    echo json_encode($response) . "\n";
```

error occours

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards: (500) {
     "error": {
      "code": 500,
      "message": null
     }
    }
```

Additional, It is works simple query - like Book API, returned proper results without error...

```
    $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
    $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
    $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Korea', $optParams);
    var_dump($results) ;
```

**Let me know your any advice.**

**Thank you for your help. :)**